# I built a Telescope, how do I start my space program?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I'm playing Oxygen Not Included, and I have just breached the surface of my rocky prison, revealing... [SPAAAAAACE!](https://youtu.be/MAW2lygZC_4).

The research tree has a bunch of rocket-based items available, and I've already researched "Basic Rocketry". What I'm curious about is how to actually unlock a destination? I've had a dupelicant working on the telescope for several cycles at this point, but he seems to have made no progress.

Do I just need to hurry up and wait? Or is there something else about my Space Program I'm leaving out?

*Playing Quality of Life III update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! So it turns out merely building a Telescope isn't enough -- even though my Duplicants immediately started using it, the progress bar never filled up. (I am going to assume this is a bug!)

Instead, you need to open the Starmap and actually *pick* an object to analyze!
[image]

Comment: It's not a bug. The telescope gives your duplicants a stress relief buff.